# MemoryCache with certain number of items

Tags: c#, caching

does MemoryCache has functionality to cache fixed number of items?

e.g. We are only interested in cache 2000 items from database. While keep adding items to the cache, if the specified number of items are exceeded, the oldest one can be removed.

If not, do we have to use another thread to do the house keeping regularly?

Comment: Do you mean [System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx)?

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't have anything built in that will limit the number of objects. Instead, it checks how much memory is being used, and compares it to the [`CacheMemoryLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.cachememorylimit.aspx). If the `CacheMemoryLimit` is exceeded, it will drop older items. You can also set items to automatically expire after a certain amount of time via the [`CacheItemPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx).

These approaches both make more sense if you're really using it as a Memory Cache. In other words, if you're worried about the tradeoff between a memory limit and the cost of fetching data, these are great ways to determine when to evict items from the cache. So ask yourself:

> Am I really trying to use this as a MemoryCache? Why do I even care if only 2000 items are loaded from the database?

If you are worried about the memory overhead, or if you are worried about the items getting out of date, there are other (better) ways to manage the cache than specifying a number of objects. If you've got some custom reason to keep a specific number of objects in a data structure, consider using a different class.

Comment: This.  Also it seems odd to limit the actual number of items in cache, typically you want as many items in cache that is possible.  Empty memory is wasted memory.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to create a new MemoryCache provider which performs the object limit management for you. This would override some of the MemoryCache methods in such as add and remove, and automatically roll-off items once the arbitrary limit (e.g. 2000 objects) has been reached.

One such implementation may look like the following:

```
public class ObjectLimitMemoryCache : MemoryCache
{
private const int ObjectLimit = 2000;
private const string IndexKey = "ObjectLimitIndexKey";

public ObjectLimitMemoryCache(string name, NameValueCollection config) 
: base (name, config)
{
}

new public static ObjectLimitMemoryCache Default { get { return new ObjectLimitMemoryCache(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new NameValueCollection());}}

public override bool Add(string key, Object value, DateTimeOffset absoluteExpiration, string region = null)
{
    try
    {
        var indexedKeys = (List<string>)(base.Get(IndexKey) ?? new List<string>());
        if (base.Add(key, value, absoluteExpiration))
        {
            string existingKey;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(existingKey = indexedKeys.FirstOrDefault(x=>x == key)))
            {
                indexedKeys.Add(key);
            }
            if (base.GetCount() > ObjectLimit)
            {
                base.Remove(indexedKeys.First());
                indexedKeys.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            base.Add(IndexKey, indexedKeys, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(2))); 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
//Log something and other fancy stuff
        throw;
    }
}
}
```

This is untested code and meant solely to illustrate an example implementation of MemoryCache. Good luck!